# UWP Bind to ObservableCollection declaratively

Tags: xaml, data-binding, uwp

I have a simple UWP page; there is a public ObservableCollection in the page code-behind:

`public ObservableCollection<Book> MyObservableColl{ get; } = new ObservableCollection<Book>();`

(note the collection consists of a single item)
I would like to bind to the collection; here is what I tried:

```
            <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel"
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Margin="50"
                        DataContext="{x:Bind MyObservableColl, Mode=OneWay}">
                <TextBox x:Name="txtTitle"
                         TextWrapping="Wrap"
                         Text="{x:Bind Title, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
```

The visual studio designer complains "the property Title was not found".
I appreciate any help to bind my text boxes to the Observable Collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the property Title was not found

`txtTitle` TextBox can't access Book item where in the `MyObservableColl` collection directly, you need place txtTitle under items control's ItemTemplate.

For example

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyObservableColl, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Book">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Title}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

For more info please refer to listview [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview?view=winrt-22621).

**Update**

For single item please refer to this xaml

```
<StackPanel
        x:Name="stackPanel"
        Grid.Row="2"
        Margin="50"
        DataContext="{x:Bind MyObservableColl[0], Mode=OneWay}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Title}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks, this has allowed me to progress. If I have a single item to display, should it be in a ListView or something else?

Comment: please refer to the above update part.